# How do I transport my game data to another computer that already has the game with Steam?

Tags: steam, papers-please

I have Papers Please on both my desktop and laptop, and was playing on my laptop while the power was out, when I rebooted it up on my desktop my newly gained progress wasn't there, but it still remained on my laptop.

I have cloud save enabled but I don't know how to transfer the data to override what's on my desktop.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/239030/discussions/0/846961716418140608/), the save file is located at

**Windows**: `%AppData%\3909\PapersPlease`
**Mac**: `~/Library/Application Support/PapersPlease/`
**Linux**: `~/.local/share/3909/PapersPlease`

So copy it from one computer to the other

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to what BlueRaja said, Cloud Save works when the internet is on. So assuming you weren't connected to any other internet connection, Cloud Save didn't work. It might've detected it after you launched the game on your PC. But since you said it didn't, use BlueRaja's way.